# Python Geopy with Google Maps API SSL Error

Tags: python, google-maps, google-api, python-requests, geopy

I found the following link:

https://towardsdatascience.com/pythons-geocoding-convert-a-list-of-addresses-into-a-map-f522ef513fd6

It shows a quick walk through on how to use Google Maps API to get latitude/longitude.  However, when I use the provided code I get an SSL error. I have a working API key as I can get the URL to work that is produced from the second code set below.

Code:

```
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3
AUTH_KEY = "HIDDEN"
geolocator = GoogleV3(api_key=AUTH_KEY)
print(geolocator.geocode("1 Apple Park Way, Cupertino, CA").point) #Apple
```

Error:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='maps.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /maps/api/geocode/json?address=1+Apple+Park+Way%2C+Cupertino%2C+CA&key=HIDDEN (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1076)')))
```

I also tried using the following:

Code:

```
import requests
import json
import urllib

# https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro
base_url= "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?"
AUTH_KEY = HIDDEN

# set up your search parameters - address and API key
parameters = {"address": "1 Apple Park Way, Cupertino, CA",
             "key": AUTH_KEY}

# urllib.parse.urlencode turns parameters into url
print(f"{base_url}{urllib.parse.urlencode(parameters)}")

r = requests.get(f"{base_url}{urllib.parse.urlencode(parameters)}")
```

I get the exact same error.  Oddly though the URL produced by `print(f"{base_url}{urllib.parse.urlencode(parameters)}")` is usable when I click on it.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by setting the verify flag to false for the second set of code using requests, and while it works is not ideal.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Both code samples work as expected for me.